# Make Local Alert Notification

Tags: ios, xamarin, notifications, push-notification, alert

I'm working with Xamarin and iOS, but I'm having a lot of trouble when it comes to notifications. I can create a local push notification that goes to the notification center, but there is no sound or indication that the notification has actually arrived. How can I make the notification an alert notification so that it appears on the screen before going to the notification hub?

Here is the code I'm currently generating the notification with:

```
//create notification
var notification = new UILocalNotification ();
notification.AlertAction = "Open App";
notification.AlertTitle = "App";
notification.AlertBody = "There has been activity in the app";
notification.SoundName = UILocalNotification.DefaultSoundName;

//display notification
UIApplication.SharedApplication.ScheduleLocalNotification (notification);
```

EDIT: 
The problem is not just sound, but that there is no feedback that an alert has been received, it just appears in the notification central silently. I am asking for permissions as well with this code:

```
var settings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(
                UIUserNotificationType.Alert
                | UIUserNotificationType.Badge
                | UIUserNotificationType.Sound,
                new NSSet());

            UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(settings);
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications();
```

Comment: so the only problem is the sound ? if yes, check in the notification permissions if sound is disabled by any chance

Comment: I updated the question, the problem is with more than just sound.

Comment: Your update doesnt change anything about my commend, did you check if you activated the permissions ?

Answer (score 6):

use 
[notification setSoundName:UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName];
it will work fine.